# Move object to 3D-Cursor but only on one axis

Tags: snapping, coordinates, 3d-cursor

I often find myself in situations where I want to move an object to just one specific coordinate of the 3d-Cursor. Like in below example I want to move a wheel along the y-axis to the center given by the 3D-cursor but I don't want to move it in the other directions (as Shift-S and Selection to Cursor would). I'm aware that I can just copy the x/y/z location of the cursor from the N-Menu. Still, is there a faster way that works with shortcuts maybe?

[image: Picture of a wheel that ought to be moved to the center specified by the 3D-Cursor]

Comment: Well I snapped the cursor to object so it centers on the x-Axis. If i could do that with snapping directly i would :/

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't have used 'X' to mean unknown :) I can't tell whether your disc has an edge or a vertex centrally aligned down the X axis running towards us. Depending on which, the snap would be to 'Vertex' or 'Edge Center', the appropriate target on the disc. The move, in Object Mode, would be GY.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible while creating the objects but you can move them all to the same z-coordinate at the end instead. To achieve this, select all the objects you want to move and then set the Y-coordinate (or whichever property to want to have in common). Then right-click the coordinate property and select 'Copy Single to Selected'.

[image]

Comment: That's a good tip I didn't know that thank you! :D